# Is there a kind of Ubuntu Wiki sitemap or contents index?

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

I feel the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com) contains treasures, but I as much feel unable to exploit its contents as much as I would like. What I miss, is a kind of contents index, may be by categories, but a classical *sitemap* would be largely fine too. Unfortunately, if I try to go to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/sitemap.xml (posting a raw URL on purpose), I get that message:

> This page does not exist yet. You can create a new empty page, or use one of the page templates.

And it only contains links to templates intended to the creation of new wiki‑pages.

I don't know it something like what I'm looking for exist (did I missed it?). A search on major search‑engines gave nothing, nor on AskUbuntu (seems the question was never ask, or else it is a stupid question and I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1):

- Index pages: See **http://wiki.ubuntu.com/FindPage**

  [RecentChanges](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecentChanges): see where people are currently working

  [TitleIndex](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TitleIndex): a list of all pages in the wiki

  [WordIndex](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WordIndex): a list of all words that are part of page title (thus, a list of the concepts in a wiki)

  [WantedPages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WantedPages): a list of linked, but not existing pages

  [OrphanedPages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OrphanedPages): a list of existing, but not linked pages

  [AbandonedPages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AbandonedPages): a list of pages that have seen no changes for long

  [RandomPage](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RandomPage): some random pages

  [PageSize](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PageSize): size statistics

  [PageHits](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PageHits): hit statistics
- For map:

  1. You can use `Local Site Map` at any page, but for example start at home:

     https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Home
  2. At the top, Click on **More Actions:** button, then select **Local Site Map**

  [image]

  Like that browse site as tree.
- For Search, you can use advanced option with most search engine. Example using Google, You can use `site:` keyword to search only in Ubuntu wiki.

  [wubi site:wiki.ubuntu.com](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=wubi%20site:wiki.ubuntu.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)